# How the consecutive numbers can be replaced with the range of number and random number should be as it is?

Tags: java

If there are numbers in which some are in sequence and some are random number, then how the consecutive numbers can be replaced with the range of number and random number should be as it is?
for eg: 1,2,3,4,5,6, 458,243
output: 1-6,458,243

Comment: We are not a free code-writing service, sorry. It is expected that you make an attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: what have you got so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved this problem..Its super simple just some if-else condition, however, I don't think about efficient way, so please follow the solution and try to efficient it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] numberList = {1,2,3,4,5,6,458,243};

        int initialSequence = -1;
        int endSequence = -5;

        for (int num = 0; num<numberList.length;num++) {
            if(num<numberList.length-1) {
                if(initialSequence == -1 && numberList[num] == numberList[num+1]-1) {
                       initialSequence = endSequence = numberList[num]; 
                    }else if(initialSequence == -1 && numberList[num] != numberList[num+1]-1){
                        System.out.print(numberList[num] + " ");
                    }else if(initialSequence != -1 && numberList[num] == numberList[num+1]-1) {
                        endSequence = numberList[num];
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.print(initialSequence + "-" + (endSequence+1) + " ");
                        initialSequence = -1;
                        endSequence = -5;
                    }

            }else {
                if(initialSequence == -1) System.out.print(numberList[num] + " ");
                else {
                    System.out.print(initialSequence + "-" + (endSequence+1) + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: most welcome @PR173. Please accept the answer and don't forgot to upvote :)